# Re-index dataframe by new range of dates

Tags: python, pandas, date-range, reindex

I have a data frame containing a number of observations:

```
date         colour     orders
2014-10-20   red        7
2014-10-21   red        10
2014-10-20   yellow     3
```

I would like to re-index the data frame and standardise the dates.

```
date         colour     orders
2014-10-20   red        7
2014-10-21   red        10
2014-10-22   red        NaN
2014-10-20   yellow     3
2014-10-21   yellow     NaN
2014-10-22   yellow     NaN
```

I though to order the data frame by `colour` and `date`, and then try to re-index it.

```
index = pd.date_range('20/10/2014', '22/10/2014')
test_df = df.sort(['colour', 'date'], ascending=(True, True))
ts = test_df.reindex(index)
ts
```

But it returns a new data frame with the right index but all `NaN` values.

```
date         colour     orders
2014-10-20   NaN        NaN
2014-10-21   NaN        NaN
2014-10-22   NaN        NaN
```

Comment: What is `index` in your example?

Comment: Hi Joris, I'm new to pandas. I think the initial data frame is actually not indexed at all. I've sorted it but didn't set any index.

Comment: But I mean, you use a variable called `index` in the line `ts = test_df.reindex(index)`. So what is that exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the initial question with the line of code missing. Ideally I would let pandas find the start and end date automatically.. like the smaller and the bigger date in the data frame. I just saw the command `test_df.resample('D')` is meant to do it, but I think I should index beforehand the test_df by 'date', which I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting from your exampe dataframe:

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
        date  colour  orders
0 2014-10-20     red       7
1 2014-10-21     red      10
2 2014-10-20  yellow       3
```

If you want to reindex on both 'date' and 'colour', one possibility is to set both as the index (a multi-index):

```
In [52]: df = df.set_index(['date', 'colour'])

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
                   orders
date       colour
2014-10-20 red          7
2014-10-21 red         10
2014-10-20 yellow       3
```

You can now reindex this dataframe, after you constructed to desired index:

```
In [54]: index = pd.date_range('20/10/2014', '22/10/2014')

In [55]: multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([index, ['red', 'yellow']])

In [56]: df.reindex(multi_index)
Out[56]:
                   orders
2014-10-20 red          7
           yellow       3
2014-10-21 red         10
           yellow     NaN
2014-10-22 red        NaN
           yellow     NaN
```

To have the same output as your example output, the index should be sorted in the second level (`level=1` as it is 0-based):

```
In [60]: df2 = df.reindex(multi_index)

In [64]: df2.sortlevel(level=1)
Out[64]:
                   orders
2014-10-20 red          7
2014-10-21 red         10
2014-10-22 red        NaN
2014-10-20 yellow       3
2014-10-21 yellow     NaN
2014-10-22 yellow     NaN
```

A possible way to generate the multi-index automatically would be (with your original frame):

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max(), freq='D'), 
                            df['colour'].unique()])
```

---

**Another way** would be to use `resample` for each group of colors:

```
In [77]: df = df.set_index('date')

In [78]: df.groupby('colour').resample('D')
```

This is simpler, but this does not give you the full range of dates for each colour, only the range of dates that is available for that colour group.

Comment: Let's say I have thousands of products (to be fair I also don't have just one column, but one for the category, a various sub-categories, etc..), how can I change this part of the code `multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([index, ['red', 'yellow']])`?

Comment: See my "A possible way to generate the multi-index automatically ..." to do this when there are a lot of values in the `colour` column

Comment: @Gianluca Did this solve your problem? Or are there still problems?