# Python Pandas DataFrame: how to get complete dates for all categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(['2021-06-06']*3 + ['2021-06-07']*3 + ['2021-06-09']*3),
    'cat': ['a', 'b', 'c']*3,
    'value': np.random.randn(9)
    })

#         date cat     value
# 0 2021-06-06   a  1.182969
# 1 2021-06-06   b  0.460896
# 2 2021-06-06   c  0.859053
# 3 2021-06-07   a  0.259080
# 4 2021-06-07   b -1.333531
# 5 2021-06-07   c  1.258963
# 6 2021-06-09   a  0.254633
# 7 2021-06-09   b  0.250557
# 8 2021-06-09   c  1.363891
```

I would like to fill in the date(s) that are missing in the `date` column, but for all unique values from the `cat` column. For `value` column, it is okey to leave there `NaN`. The following code seems to achieve what I need, but I was just wondering if there is an easier way to do the same.

```
from itertools import product

df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    product(
        pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max(), freq="D"),
        df.cat.unique()
        )
    )\
    .set_axis(["date", "cat"], axis=1)\
    .merge(df, how="left", on=["date", "cat"])
    
#          date cat     value
# 0  2021-06-06   a  1.090784
# 1  2021-06-06   b -0.479246
# 2  2021-06-06   c  1.886213
# 3  2021-06-07   a  1.477877
# 4  2021-06-07   b -0.026864
# 5  2021-06-07   c -1.432626
# 6  2021-06-08   a       NaN
# 7  2021-06-08   b       NaN
# 8  2021-06-08   c       NaN
# 9  2021-06-09   a  0.055170
# 10 2021-06-09   b -2.060127
# 11 2021-06-09   c  0.402082
```

Comment: instead of a merge you can create a multiindex using the product method and then use `df.reindex` after the groupby. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421256/re-index-dataframe-by-new-range-of-dates

Comment: I looked at the answers there, but to be honest, I was not sure how to set the multiindex, so I will just go with @Shubham Sharma's solution. Appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `pivot` the dataframe to reshape it into wide format, then reindex the dataframe using `asfreq` in order to fill the missing dates then `stack` the frame to reshape it back to long format

```
df.pivot('date', 'cat').asfreq('D').stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
```

---

```
         date cat     value
0  2021-06-06   a  1.312101
1  2021-06-06   b  0.427093
2  2021-06-06   c  0.889593
3  2021-06-07   a -0.145082
4  2021-06-07   b -0.262260
5  2021-06-07   c  0.827072
6  2021-06-08   a       NaN
7  2021-06-08   b       NaN
8  2021-06-08   c       NaN
9  2021-06-09   a  0.273335
10 2021-06-09   b -0.201577
11 2021-06-09   c -1.294582
```

Comment: For this example dataset, this works swimmingly, but for some reason, in my real usecase, the asfreq('D') produced all NaNs for the value column. Do you happen to know what might cause that?

Comment: Get it working, now, thanks a lot. My date column in the real usecase was a string, not date. Honestly, I would expect pandas throwing an error, and not to produce all NaNs in that case. Anyway, thanks for a neat solution.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny Make sure you have converted the `date` column to pandas `datetime` type